# Как вызвать диалоговое окно api facebook из другого класса

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook-api

У меня есть класс который вызывает диалоговое окно с просьбой опубликовать запись на стерне facebook.

```
class ApiFacebook : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle ?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext())
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
    fun shareLinks (shareDialog :ShareDialog) {
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent:: class.java)) {
            val linkContent = ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("Androidlift")
                    .setContentDescription("Androidlift blog")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://androidlift.info"))
                    .build()
            shareDialog.show(linkContent)
        }
    }
}
```

Диалоговое окно можно вызвать только в этом класс `ApiFacebook`, а если обраться с другого класса `ApiFacebook().shareLinks(ShareDialog(this))` Я получаю ошибку. О том что я не инициализировал sdk facebook.

Я могу в нужном классе инициализировать sdk таки путем

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext())
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this)
```

А потом вызвать `ApiFacebook().shareLinks(ShareDialog(this))`. Но мне бы хотелось использовать первый вариант, это возможно без унаследования от класса `ApiFacebook`?

Comment: 1. Инициализируйте SDK в классе Application - так оно будет всегда инициализировано. 2. Вынесите метод `shareLinks ` в `companion object` - так вам не надо будет создавать экземпляр активити для вызова метода (получится аналог статического метода явы)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, работает. Вы можете ответить на мой вопрос, чтобы я его отметил как верный. И еще вопрос, статические методы таким образом наверное кушают больше оперативной памяти?

Comment: В ответ написал) Точно не скажу про потребление памяти. Но точно могу сказать что не стоит об этом беспокоиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Инициализируйте `SDK` в классе-наследнике класса `Application` (не забыв прописать его в манифесте) - так оно будет всегда инициализировано.
2. Вынесите метод `shareLinks` в `companion object` класса активити - так вам не надо будет создавать экземпляр активити для вызова метода (получится аналог статического метода на `Java`)